# Angular Formly Giant CheckBox and Duplicate Labels Issues

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-formly

I have a link to a plunker I have created using Angular and Angular formly dynamic forms along with angular-message and angular-animate to add in some flair...this is more of a proof of concept thing I am working on and will be taking some of these ideas and implementing them for a new portal I am helping build at work.

However I am having an issue I haven't figured out exactly how to fix yet:

Inputs and labels are working great, however Checkboxes and Select Dropdowns are not working as intended...

All of these were having duplicate labels at first. I added in a checkbox template and that resolved the duplicate labels issue, however it added in another issue with making the checkboxes humongous and centering them, which I don't want.

The select dropdown still has the duplicate label and I have not figured out how to to style the contents of the dropdown list to bold.

If someone might be able to take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

To access the checkboxes, you need to validly complete the form(or at least enter in a valid 10 digit number at the bottom) after you do that, the first check box pops up asking if you are over 18, then another check box pops up asking if you live in the US. If both those are checked, then the select dropdown list pops up with the states.

Here is the link to the plunker, any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://plnkr.co/edit/ADpFUHb2U2j9Q93uWUwN?p=info

```
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="checkbox-template.html">
  <input type="{{options.templateOptions.type || 'checkbox'}}"
       class="form-control"
       id="{{id}}"
       formly-dynamic-name="id"
       formly-custom-validation="options.validators"
       placeholder="{{options.templateOptions.placeholder}}"
       aria-describedby="{{id}}_description"
       ng-required="options.templateOptions.required"
       ng-disabled="options.templateOptions.disabled"
       ng-model="model[options.key]">
</script>
```

PS: Also one last thing...I wanted to make the input boxes smaller, however when I do that the checkboxes end up in the middle of the text(when they are properly sized without the template and the dual label---which is probably why they are in the middle of the screen now---its around the same place they would be when they are not huge)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what it is, but it seems related to the custom templates...

I looked up some other code on the formly website examples that do similar things with the messages without creating those templates in that manner and once I changed the code it went away and stopped doing it...

Answer (score 0):

In some cases the label was showing both before and after the checkbox.

I took a look at the ngx-formly bootstrap [source](https://github.com/formly-js/ngx-formly/blob/master/src/bootstrap/src/lib/wrappers/form-field.wrapper.ts) for the form-field wrapper, and saw that an additional label was being conditionally output. But it also showed how to suppress it.

So, I just set 'hideLabel' to true and I was back to just one label for the checkbox!

```
  fieldBoolean.templateOptions.label = "Are you sure?";
  fieldBoolean.templateOptions['hideLabel'] = true;
```